# vxworks - ioctl(SIOCGIFCONF) error

Tags: networking, embedded, ioctl, vxworks

```
ioctl(socketDescriptor, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifconf)
```

This `ioctl` call works fine when I use it in normal RTP, but gives the following error when used in `.a` libraries.

> ENXIO i.e. "this driver or device was not found".

Answer (score 0):

this is because the vxWorks has changed the underlying implementation of ioct(SIOCGIFCONFIG) form vxWorks 6.9.3 to vxWorks 6.9.4.6